# Blender shows white screen on external monitors when laptop lid is closed

Tags: windows

I have an HP ProBook core I7 and Blender works well on this system, but...

When I want to work on my external monitors, Blender shows a white screen when it's starting up or the Blender screen is dead and doesn't respond on anything when my Laptop Lid is closed.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of battery saving feature for your hardware, notcan issue specifically with Blender

Answer (score 0):

It might also be an issue with the graphics driver... or drivers (plural). A laptop like that might have both integrated Intel graphics and a graphics card from NVIDIA or AMD. It's possible, I think, that when you close the lid the power settings cause the NVIDIA or AMD graphics to be disabled and the system uses the Intel graphics instead. You might want to see if there's an Intel graphics management tool. Look for "Graphics options" when you right-click on the backdrop of your desktop. See if there's a way to disable Intel graphics completely, and try again. Or at least, disable when connected to a power supply. It would be useful to know what graphics hardware is in your laptop.